# Firebase google auth web JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am successfully integrated firebase google auth web. I was getting this below response. how can i get only **additionalUserInfo** in js 
[This is response after successfully sign in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gCxw.png) 
This is code

```
function googleSignin() {
    base_proveider =new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(base_proveider).then(function(result){
        console.log(result)
        console.log("success google account linked")
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err)
        console.log('fialed to do')

    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the doc for [`signInWithPopup()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithpopup), it returns a Promise which resolves with a [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential), which is "a structure containing a `User`, an `AuthCredential`, the `operationType`, and any additional user information that was returned from the identity provider".

So you have to do as follows:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(base_proveider)
.then(function(result){  
    // result is a UserCredential
    var additionalUserInfo = result.additionalUserInfo;

    console.log(result.additionalUserInfo.profile["name"])
    console.log("success google account linked")
})
```